# Initialize a custom type doesn't work with var but works with :=

Tags: variables, go, types

I'm trying to initialize an ErrNegativeSqrt, which is a custom float64 type, but if I do it with `var` it doesn't work.

Take a look in `func Sqrt(x float64) (float64, error)`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ErrNegativeSqrt float64

func (e *ErrNegativeSqrt) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprint("cannot Sqrt negative number: %f", float64(*e))
}

func Sqrt(x float64) (float64, error) {
    if x < 0 {
        var err ErrNegativeSqrt = x
        // This works: err := ErrNegativeSqrt(x)
        return x, &err
    }

    z := x / 2
    i := 1

    for prev_z := 0.0; z != prev_z && Abs(z-prev_z) > 0.000000000000001; i++ {
        prev_z = z
        z -= (z*z - x) / (2 * z)
    }

    return z, nil
}

func Abs(x float64) float64 {
    if x < 0 {
        x = -x
    }
    return x
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(2))
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(-2))
}
```

The error is: `./prog.go:15:7: cannot use x (type float64) as type ErrNegativeSqrt in assignment`

Why does it happen? Isn't it the same as the assignment with `:=`?

[Here there is the playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/svMq3Dg4jCa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations):

```
var err ErrNegativeSqrt = x
```

You explicitly give `err` a type of `ErrNegativeSqrt`, and you try to assign `x` to it but `x` is of type `float64` which is not assignable to a value of type `ErrNegativeSqrt`. [Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) rules don't apply, `float64` and `ErrNegativeSqrt` are 2 different, distinct types (although the latter has the former as its [underlying type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types), so they are [convertible](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) one another).

When you use this [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

```
err := ErrNegativeSqrt(x)
```

You explicitly [convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) `x` to `ErrNegativeSqrt`, so `x`'s type will be inferred to be `ErrNegativeSqrt`.

You may do the same when using the `var` keyword:

```
var err ErrNegativeSqrt = ErrNegativeSqrt(x)
```

Or simply:

```
var err = ErrNegativeSqrt(x)
```

Which is exactly what the [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) is a short form for.

### Notes

As said earlier, `var err ErrNegativeSqrt = x` is invalid because [assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) rules don't apply:

> A value `x` is assignable to a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - `x`'s type is identical to `T`.
> - `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical [underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) type.
> - `T` is an interface type and `x` [implements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) `T`.
> - `x` is a bidirectional channel value, `T` is a channel type, `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical element types, and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a defined type.
> - `x` is the predeclared identifier `nil` and `T` is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.
> - `x` is an untyped [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) [representable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Representability) by a value of type `T`.

As you can see, the second rule "almost" covers what we want to do here:

> `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical underlying types and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a defined type

The reason why it's just "almost" is because both `ErrNegativeSqrt` and `float64` are named ([defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions)) types.

When you do:

```
var err ErrNegativeSqrt = 1.0
```

This works because here you are assigning an *untyped* [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) `1.0` which can take the required type when needed (like in the above assignment). Since you are assigning to `err` of type `ErrNegativeSqrt`, the untyped constant `1.0` can take the type `ErrNegativeSqrt` (because `ErrNegativeSqrt`'s underlying type is `float64`, and `1.0` is an untyped floating-point constant). This case is exactly the last assignability rule:

> `x` is an untyped [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) [representable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Representability) by a value of type `T`.

If you would do:

```
var err ErrNegativeSqrt = float64(1.0) // FAIL!!
```

This would again fail just as your example in the question, because here we're using a *typed* constant which cannot change type arbitrarily, there is no assignability rule allowing this.

Read blog post [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants) for more details how constants work in Go.

Comment: Ok, this is reasonable. But I can't understand why sometime it works!
Here an example: https://play.golang.org/p/kFGGnfqpnUi